# Why view is not displaying in design in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-recyclerview

I can run my app but the problem is displaying nothing in the design part then how can I add other views to finish it. Is there a special feature to hide? because generally it shows everything in android studio design. I share a pic check it out.
[image]

Thank you!!!

Comment: Hey Can You Give the link of your xml file? I think its not about the caches its in your layout fault!

Comment: https://github.com/Madhanbg/xml/blob/main/reg

Comment: @MadhanMohan try to rebuild the project

Comment: I tried it but no use

Comment: Can you explain please how is this a Firebase question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to see the actual content? If so click the blue diamond in the top left and select "Design"

If you suspect there is an error loading the preview  press "Force Refresh Layout". If that doesn't work go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart